# Operands could not be broadcast together

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

The score is being returned as nan and I.m getting the following error in score function:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,) (75,)

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',')
x = data[:, 0:2]
y = data[:, 2]
from sklearn import model_selection
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y)

def fit(x_train, y_train):
    m1 = ((x_train[:, 1] **2) * x_train[:, 0] * y_train - (x_train[:, 0] * x_train[:, 1]) * (x_train[:, 1] * y_train))/((x_train[:, 0] **2) * (x_train[:,1] **2) - (x_train[:, 0] * x_train[:, 1]) **2)
    m2 = ((x_train[:, 0] **2) * x_train[:, 1] * y_train - (x_train[:, 1] * x_train[:, 0]) * (x_train[:, 0] * y_train))/((x_train[:, 1] **2) * (x_train[:,0] **2) - (x_train[:, 1] * x_train[:, 0]) **2)
    return m1, m2, c
def predict(x, m1, m2, c):
    return (x_train[:, 0] * m1) + (x_train[:, 1] * m2) + c

def score(y_truth, y_pred):
    u = ((y_truth - y_pred) ** 2).sum()
    v = ((y_truth - y_truth.mean()) ** 2).sum()
    return  1 - u/v

m1, m2, c = fit(x_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = predict(x, m1, m2, c)
print("Train Score ", score(y_train, y_train_pred))
y_test_pred = predict(x, m1, m2, c)
print("Test Score ", score(y_test, y_test_pred))
```

Comment: Please include the full error message, and **remove** whatever code comes *after* the error (it is never executed, hence useless in locating your issue). Also, your title does not seem to reflect your post body - please edit accordingly

Comment: From code score returns `1 - u/v`. Having no idea of how your data looks like, if v is zero, `u/v` will be `nan` and in python or numpy `nan` value corrupts all operations i.e `1 - nan = nan`. For the broadcast error, check the sizes of your array that they coincide